# How to update Recoil JS Atom Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, recoiljs

I have an Atom object defined like this:

```
export const walletInfo = atom({
  key: "walletInfo",
  default: {
    connected: false,
    someString: "",
    someInt: 0,
    someOtherInfo: "",
  },
});
```

The question is, how do I change only single value in Atom object without overwriting everything else? For example, how do I **set connected: true** and keep the rest of the information?

The code below will "erase" the rest of the object

```
import { walletInfo } from "../src/atoms";
const [wallet, setWallet] = useRecoilState(walletInfo);

setWallet({
   connected: true,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the previous state and updated state like this

```
setWallet((prevState) => ({
   ...prevState,
   connected: true,
}));
```